# Angularjs, Como criar Checkbox para inserir array no MongoDb

Tags: javascript, angularjs, array, mongodb

Criei uma coleção no mondoDB chamada **Mangas**, onde tem "**nome, autor, genero** e **info**"

**Genero** é array.

Tenho um formulario que vai receber os valores nome, autor e info, o Checkbox precisa vir preenchido como Array com valores a serem inserados com o forumulario

**Pergunta.**
Como fazer um Checkbox que tenha 2 opções **"Aventura** e **Ação"** e insira no mongoDB como array?

Igual a coleção abaixo.

MongoDB Mangas

```
db.mangas.insert({
    nome:'Toriko',
    autor:'não sei',
    genero:['aventura','ação'],
    info:'...'
    })
```

**Index.html**

```
<tr>
  <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="manga.nome"></td>
  <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="manga.autor"></td>
  <!-- aqui precisa ser a CHECKBOX que irá ter os valores do array e inseridos no GENERO -->
  <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="manga.info"></td>



  <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addManga()">Add manga</button></td>
</tr>

     <tr ng-repeat="manga in mangas">
       <td>{{manga.nome}}</td>
       <td>{{manga.autor}}</td>
       <td><!-- aqui vai listar o valor recebido do checkbox --></td>
       <td>{{manga.info}}</td>
     </tr>
```

**Função addManga**

```
$scope.addManga = function() {
    console.log($scope.manga);
    $http.post('/mangas', $scope.manga).success(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
       refresh();
    })};
```

Comment: Só para ver se eu entendi: a sua duvida é sobre como criar uma lista de checkboxes ligadas a um array no seu escopo, isso?

Comment: Isso, correto, porque fazer isso? no **genero**, seria um array, o checkboxex teria 2 opções exemplo:"Ação", "Aventura", no formulario, seleciona as 2 opções do checkboxes e envia como array para mongoDB, assim seria criar uma tabela de genero e procurar todos os valores de Ação e Aventura.

Comment: @JuanBiscaia Não sei como criar um checkboxes com os valores do array e como criar uma função para enviar o valor do checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz uma SPA basica mostrando como você pode usar uma função no `ng-click` de cada input checkbox para adicionar ou remover itens do seu array de generos.

Esse app tem uma diferença, ao invés de adicionar strings na lista eu adiciono objetos, um para cada genero, assim você consegue dar mais utilidade para eles.

Usei o [guia de estilo criado por esse cara](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/i18n/pt-BR.md) para montar essa SPA.

## **[Link para o Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LGcJJ4V6aoIxKJBAupUh?p=preview)**

Comment: Incrível, ficou perfeito , erá isso que fiquei procurando, muito obrigado, Sucesso.